# How to wrap first word of page title in span in drupal 7

Tags: theming

I want to implement it with theme_preprocess function. Every my attempt fails.

```
function mdrupal_mono_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['title'] = drupal_get_title($variables['node']);
  $title = $variables['title'];
  if($title) {
    $words = explode(' ', $title);
    $words[0] = '<span>' . $words[0] . '</span>';
    $title = implode(' ', $words);
  }
}
```

Comment: `drupal_get_title` doesn't accept parameters

Comment: If I am sure, then you want to display html markup within title of the node.

Comment: yes @JayendraKainthola

Comment: @DalerMadaminov, you can use better approach than this.

Comment: and what would that be? @JayendraKainthola

Comment: where are you passing that `title` variable?

Comment: oh! thanks to everybody I solved it! I should have used $variables['node']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case this is working perfectly in `bartik_preprocess_page()` (bartik theme):

```
  $pageTitle = drupal_get_title();
  $pageTitleArr = explode(' ', $pageTitle);
  $firstPart = '<span>' . $pageTitleArr[0] . '</span>';
  $pageTitleArr[0] = $firstPart;
  $title = implode(' ', $pageTitleArr);

  drupal_set_title($title, PASS_THROUGH);
  $variables['title'] = $title;
```

Comment: you should also sanitize and strip html tags or unsafe characters (except `span` tag) in `title` variable..

Answer (score 1):

Not really a Drupal question, but you're setting the wrong variable

```
$title = implode(' ', $words);
```

should be

```
$variables['title'] = implode(' ', $words);
```

Or, change

```
$title = $variables['title'];
```

to

```
$title = &$variables['title'];
```

instead. Either will work

Comment: yeah that was a mistake, but the code still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can add some `pseudotags` like `[span]` or `[i]` in your node title and can use below `function` in your `template.php` file.

```
function bb2html($text) {
  $bbcode = array(
                  "[strong]", "[/strong]",
                  "[b]",  "[/b]",
                  "[u]",  "[/u]",
                  "[i]",  "[/i]",
                  "[em]", "[/em]"
                );
  $htmlcode = array(
                "<strong>", "</strong>",
                "<strong>", "</strong>",
                "<u>", "</u>",
                "<em>", "</em>",
                "<em>", "</em>"
              );
  return str_replace($bbcode, $htmlcode, $text);
}
```

You need to use `<?php print bb2html($head_title); ?>` in your `page.tpl` file.

For more reference, you can check [this](https://drupal.org/node/28537).